# Retrive value of a variable within the HTML within JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm looking to set a variable based on some security for the user logged into and then use that value within JQuery.

This is the setting the variable:

```
    <c:set var="hasResDetailAccess" value="false"/>
```

What JQuery would be used to retrive that vlaue

```
    jQuery(document).ready(
        function() {
            var display = $(#frank).text();
        });
```

Comment: use `<c:set var="hasResDetailAccess" value="false" id="someId"/>` and `var display = $('#someId').val();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you are trying with `<c:set>` and `jQuery` both are different thing. `<c:set>` is useful while translating jsp to servlet i.e. on server side
and 'jQuery' is used to process value on the client side i.e. in the browser.

So if you want a variable within jQuery just add it to any scope i.e request,session,context or application as per your requirement and retrieve it in jsp.

For example in `Servlet`,

add

```
request.setAttribute("hasResDetailAccess",hasResDetailAccess);
```

And in JSP just put code as below,

```
jQuery(document).ready(
        function() {
            var  hasResDetailAccess= ${hasResDetailAccess} ;
        });
```

`${hasResDetailAccess}` will fetch value of the variable regardless of the scope and set it to the `jQuery` variable `hasResDetailAccess. And latter on you can retrieve that jQuery Variable in HTML page anywhere any point of time you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the value in a hidden input an retrieve it from there:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<c:out value="${hasResDetailAccess}"/>" id="hasResDetailAccess">
```

and retrieve it with

```
var display = $('#hasResDetailAccess').val();
```